# Sum of two int with Logical Operators only

Tags: binary, logic

So far i found the method to get the carry for a sum of two bits and one carry : `int carry = a&b|a&c|b&c`;

I found the method to get the final output of a sum of two bits and one carry : `int output = a^b^c`;

I also found a method to get the sum of an int and add one : `addOne(2) = 3` for exemple.

I know that i need to use these three methods (carry(a,b,c), outpout(a,b,c), addOne(x)) to get the sum of two bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one bit (`c0` is carry-in):

```c
s0= a0^b0^c0;
cout0 = (a0&b0)|(c0&(a0^b0));
```

Chain two full-adders together (cout to cin) for a 2-bit number:

```c
c0 = 0;
s0 = a0^b0^c0;
cout0 = (a0&b0)|(c0&(a0^b0));
s1 = a1^b1^cout0;
cout1 = (a1&b1)|(cout0&(a1^b1));
```

I'll leave the simplification as an exercise for the reader (what is `A XOR 0`, `A AND 0`, etc.?).

You could also look at the logic for carry-lookahead adders, but the ripple-carry adder made of full-adders is the simplest to grasp.